# Having real difficulty on the DNA (Biohazard) level in Jets'n'Guns

Tags: jets-and-guns

This game is nightmarishly hard. I've made it up to the level where you have to collect the DNA but after several days and probably 50+ attempts I've only made it about 50% of the way through the level (and that was only once).

I've tried a couple of loadouts but I am really struggling. Anyone have any advice for doing this level? It really needs a checkpoint!

Comment: Can you list what loadouts you tried?

Comment: Honestly, I tried everything. I actually did this level in the end after a billion attempts using a mining laser shooting 45 degrees down and some bombs, plus some other generic front shooting weapons (no missiles). I'm just as stuck on the next level though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently picked Jets N Guns back up.  I beat it ages ago on the normal/medium difficulty; it's not an easy game.  I've found that Gold seems to have made it much harder.    I've been following video walkthroughs to help out (until I got stymied and haven't played since last week).

[I'm referencing this video, specifically starting at ~12 minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29jbpKdxJG0).

Here's the weapons I have stuck to:

1. Superkiller Mk1: it's expensive but puts out good damage for minimal heat generation (it actually will generate a wee little bit when fired).
2. Daisycutter Mk III: moderate heat generation when upgraded, but solid to good damage.
3. Rail Gun: I swear this weapon outperforms it's statistical listing.  It does generate a good deal of heat.  But even at a a couple of upgrades it seemed to do better damage than a DaisyCutter at +1-2 levels.  However, I ditched it eventually and was not using it on this level (I basically replaced it with the Superkiller).
4. Monkey Maniac bombs - this is a surprisingly effective weapon even on "space" levels (that is, levels without a proper ground).  This does a *lot* of damage on impact, and only costs 130k-140k to fully upgrade.  Great weapon.
5. Homing missiles - at varying levels of upgrade.  It's not agreat, but it's solid.
6. Autotrack Minigun - expensive to upgrade.  It's decent.

I was probably running Max Supperkiller, level 4-5 Daiscutter, Max Monkey Maniac, and a little bit of Minigun/homing missiles.  I was using the Red Baron hull.  I was experimenting with a level of armor (which just gives more health), but I think I ultimately ditched that.

I did this mission recently (I got stuck farther into the game though and have not played in around a week and a half).  It probably took me a dozen tries, if not more.  It's tough.  Learning enemy positions and patterns helps.  It also helps, I think, to knock out the DNA collection ASAP so you can stay focused on the already difficult gameplay.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll give these loadouts a try. I always seem to be just a little too underpowered to cut through the enemies. I think if I had about 400,000 credits more the game would be much more balanced.

Comment: This is a problem I've found in gold.  I am like 5 missions past the "final" ship, and I still can't afford to run it (upgrading to it just cuts too deeply into available funds).  I swear the pre-gold version of the game wasn't like that.  I do love that you buy and sell everything at cost - it allows experimentation.  But the game just feels much more difficult than it used to.

Comment: Thanks. I had died some 30 times on this level without getting even to 40%. After changing to this weapon set I finished the level on the first try.

Comment: @skoll good to hear!

Answer (score -1):

you can use a cheat code. press the " ` " button to unlock the command bar. in the command bar type : Arnold_for_president this will make you immortal ( if you use a cheat code, you will be marked as "!!!cheater!!!" in your license).